# Adding an LSTM layer to my autoencoder in keras

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras

I have this auto-encoder model built in keras with tensorflow backend

```
encoded = Dense(units=600, activation='relu')(input_img)
encoded = Dense(units=500, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded = Dense(units=bottleneck, activation='relu')(encoded)
decoded = Dense(units=500, activation='relu')(encoded)
decoded = Dense(units=600, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = Dense(units=img_size, activation='sigmoid')(decoded)
```

The input to the encoder is a one-dimensional array i.e [1,2,3,4,5] or in other words, a vector of an image

I'd like to add an LSTM layer in to improve my results, however, my understanding it that an LSTM requires 3 dimensional data, and I want to keep my data as a vector. Could someone give me an example of how I could integrate a layer like this using reshaping perhaps? All of my attempts thus far have failed.

Comment: I don't think an LSTM is suitable for an image because you don't predict pixel N from the previous k pixels. LSTMs are more suitable for NLP tasks because meaning is derived from sequences of words. But if you really want to do this, your vector should be `[[1], [2], ..., [5]]`

Comment: My image is a spectrogram, and I hoped to feed it to the lstm sequentially some how??? and then have the lstm return a 1d vector for the rest of the model

Answer (score 1):

keras LSTM require dimension (number of batch, time step, features) so you need to change from your 1D array which I assume it represents, 1 example, 1 feature and 5 time steps, [1,2,3,4,5] to (1,5,1) from (your number of example, number of time step, number of feature) `np.array([1,2,3,4,5]).reshape((1,5,1))`. And you need to reshape the output also, to (number of batch, time step, predicted value), for example, [2,3,4,5,6] to `np.array([2,3,4,5,6]).reshape((1,5,1))`. So, now you can add LSTM.

**Example**

```
number_of_steps = 5
number_of_feature = 1
latent_dimension = 10
bottleneck = 2
input_of_model= Input(shape=(number_of_steps,number_of_feature))

# just in case you want state_h, state_c for something else
lstm_output, state_h, state_c = LSTM(latent_dimension, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)(input_of_model)

encoded = Dense(units=600, activation='relu')(lstm_output)
encoded = Dense(units=500, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded = Dense(units=bottleneck, activation='relu')(encoded)
decoded = Dense(units=500, activation='relu')(encoded)
decoded = Dense(units=600, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = Dense(units=number_of_feature, activation='sigmoid')(decoded)

M = Model(inputs=[input_of_model], outputs=[decoded])
M.compile(keras.optimizers.Adam(),loss='mse')
M.summary()
M.fit(x=np.array([1,2,3,4,5]).reshape((1,5,1)), y=np.array([2,3,4,5,6]).reshape((1,5,1)), epochs=200)
```

Comment: Would this work if I have a list of vectors to train off of? or only with one vector?

Comment: yes, you need to convert all of your input data to 3D tensor and specify your batch size

Comment: I will attempt to figure this out myself, although I keep getting errors when trying to reshape my data

Comment: Also why would the last layer of the decoded layer be the number of features? I'd expect it to be the number of timesteps

Comment: because in this example, it try to predict the value of the next timestep which happen to have the same length as input because you try to build autoencoder.

Comment: Instead of reshaping my data to a vector, then reshaping the data, I decided to keep it in its 2d form, which is already formatted to match the lstm. However, I am receiving an error stating "Invalid argument: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order." Oddly, it still trains the network, though it's unclear to me whether it is working or not.

Comment: yes, actually I also ask the same question on stackoverflow 2 weeks ago, still no answer. It has some thing to do with loop in the graph. some say that it will converge normally some say that it can mess up training, I am not certain what is the answer.